# Как прямо передать запрос к базе из веб-страницы?

Tags: mysql, php, html, sql

Имеется в виду маленькая страничка на PHP & MySQL, где есть поле для ввода запроса и кнопка - "исполнить". А под этим полем генерировалась бы табличка или писались какие-то другие данные, которые возвращает СУБД.

"В поле input я ввожу, к примеру, Select * from MyTable И на етой же странице мне показывают всю БД"

Спасибо за то, что вы есть.

Comment: Конкретней сформулируйте вопрос. Какие поля, что надо вводить, что должно быть в итоге?

Comment: Да) Сделайте мне что-нибудь и как-нибудь для чего-нибудь))

Comment: В поле input я ввожу, к примеру, Select * from MyTable
И на етой же странице мне показывают всю БД

Answer (score 4):

**У кого будет доступ к этому полю?** Если для всех — конец вашей базе.

Можно конечно настроить необходимого пользователя и дать ему привилегии только на `select`.

**А вообще такое делается обычно:**

- создаем форму
- пишим обработчик, который принимает значение поля и вставляет его в функцию mysql_query()
- далее разбираем результат который возвратил ваш запрос
- **profit!**

Вообще, как сказал **[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)**, вам что не хватает **[phpMyAdmin](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin)**?